# User complaining of Android app 'disappearing' following an update

Tags: android

A user of one of my Android apps has reported that his version 'disappeared' following an update. None of the other (thousands of) users have reported issues.

```
This morning I tried to open up the app but could not get anything. 
I tried and tried and then physically turned my phone off and back on. 
Now the icon has disappeared.
```

He has a lot of data stored in the app, so removing and re-installing isn't an option.

```
I think the problem has been caused by another apps update which happened yesterday. 
I can see your icon in my apps list but it is the only one that is black and white, all the rest are in colour.
When I view the properties of your app it says: 
Storage 20.00KB
Application 0.00KB
Data 20.00KB
It gives an option to clear data or uninstall.
My memory card, which I haven't removed, says I have 55mb of data left.
```

What could have caused this, is there anything I can do to avoid this happening to users in the future and is there anything I can suggest to remedy his problem?

Comment: well... if you're willing to bend over backwards for this user, and you know where you're storing the data in your app, you can write a side loaded app that they can use to retrieve their data (or back it up)... however, nothing in this description sounds like anything I've ever heard before so it may be some totally one-off glitch. In any event, SO isn't the right place for this question.

Comment: Where should I ask it? Had a look at the Android StackExchange, but that seems to be for Android users.

Comment: Unfortunately there may not be a Stack for advance Android usability issues. There's probably a Google hosted Android forum for bug reports of this kind.  If you do find that this is a reproducible bug that other developers need to watch out for (and if you discover what's causing it) please post the answer here.

Comment: One idea that comes to mind is that perhaps there's insufficient free space for the installation of the upgrade to complete.  However, that's probably an issue with internal storage, not strictly related to his report of minimal free space on the SD card.  Of course if he's running some alternate rom apps to SD thing, then it would be very relevant.